# Error: 'HelloWorld' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

App.vue file

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  hello-world
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
</script>
```

HelloWorld.vue file

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  h1 {{ msg }}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const msg = ref<string>("Hello World!!!");
</script>
```

What is the issue and how to fix it? Getting this issue when using typescript, composition API, and pug templating together in vue3. And the concern is how to import a component using composition API and use that in pug template?

Comment: The problem is that you import it for nothing, to fix it, either don't import it, either use this function/component/class/variable (idk what this is)

Comment: HelloWorld is a component. And if I remove the import, I am getting vue warning in console failed to resolve component: hello-world, and a blank screen is displayed in the browser.

Comment: And without importing the component, how to use that in the template.

Comment: Edit you question and provide code, we can't guess how you used this component

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue comes from preinstalling typescript. Removing typescript as the script language should do the trick then:

```
<script setup>
```

instead of

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

If you don't want to remove it then try to figure out how typescript-components need to look different from plain js ones. Sorry I don't know much about Typescript, all I know is that it changes how the components work because they rely more on Typescript now instead of javascript. But I would guess that there's information on the vue 3 documentation about working with typescript.